# page object watir cucumber test for file being downloaded

Tags: cucumber, watir, page-object-gem

I'm trying to test that a file downloaded is initialized when i click on an image. So far i've been unable to find anything that seems to work with page object.

More specifically i'm looking for a way to handle the download dialogue pop up and to verify that file.exe has begun downloading.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate some option when you launch your browser. Here an example I use :

```
# create the folder location
download_directory = "#{Dir.pwd}/downloads/"
download_directory.gsub!("/", "\\") if Selenium::WebDriver::Platform.windows?
# Create the firefox profile
profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
profile['browser.download.dir'] = download_directory
profile['download.prompt_for_download'] = false
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/octet-stream,text/csv,application/pdf"
profile['network.http.use-cache'] = false
# launch FF
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, profile: profile
```

Then you don't need to handle the window, but only to check the downloaded file in the folder you define.

For chrome, you can't use a profile, but should use preferences.

```
# Create the prefs
prefs = {
    download: {
        prompt_for_download: false,
        default_directory: @download_directory
    }
}
# Launch chrome
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, prefs: prefs
```

And no, I don't find a solution for internet explorer yet.